# Excel: Check if date is in a list of date ranges and if so use value from other cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I hava a tab containing a list of users and start and end dates (for when they use a resource). In another tab I want to visualise which user uses the resource when. I want to visualise this by showing a date in each column and in the row below show the name of the user using the resource at that date.

So the input data looks like this (European date format dd/mm/yy):
[image: Input table]

And I would like the result to look like this:
[image: Output]

I know how to compare dates and check if a date is in a specified range, what I am struggling with is how to check if a date is in a list of date ranges (as in the input) and then assign the value of another column as value. It'll probably involve `INDEX` and `MATCH`, but I can't figure out how to tie it together.

Comment: sort on column B and use VLOOKUP with the fourth criterion as TRUE.

Comment: Echoing @ScottCraner. This is the real use-case for vlookup's range_lookup argument.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table1 is at Sheet1 and table2 is in Sheet2.. in Sheet2 cell A4 enter :

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$3,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!A3>=Sheet1!$B$1:$B$3)*(Sheet2!A3<=Sheet1!$C$1:$C$3),0))
```

then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

then drag the formula right-wards..

please share if it works.. (or not).. Hope it helps.